# What is "trek-leertje" and what it was used for in the 17th century Dutch Republic?

Tags: europe, 17th-century

Encountered this expression in the writing of the Dutch scientist Antonie van Leeuwenhoek. In [this passage from his *Arcana naturae detecta*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Lj1lh0YOzS0C&pg=PA465&lpg=PA465&dq=%22corii%20particula%22&source=bl&ots=ozM41gYjyk&sig=ACfU3U3tdppf5WNCRBh7fFXrybnWmKmduQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwibq8TB_br7AhWxUqQEHbVPCU44ChDoAXoECBUQAw#v=onepage&q=%22corii%20particula%22&f=false) ([another version](https://books.google.com/books?id=fAFMAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA425&lpg=PA425&dq=puerum%20ludentem%20vidi&source=bl&ots=AVp912yPhj&sig=ACfU3U156uJvw-E-RThGrNMOOQ2GUDHcxQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjbuI2q_Lr7AhW2T6QEHVwgCGYQ6AF6BAgVEAM#v=onepage&q=puerum%20ludentem%20vidi&f=false) little different) , he describes a tool that he used to play with in his childhood; He mentions that this tool is called **"een trek-leertje"**; then describes what is this tool, which, to my understating from the text, is a piece of round leather (*particula corii*) about two thumbs in diameter with a small hole (*foraminulum*) in the middle through which a small thread (*funiculus*) can pass and then be closed with knot/knob (*nodus*). Then he goes on to either describe the game or his experiments in which description I got somewhat lost.

Despite the article *een*, it seems that Antonie is referring to a specific thing that the readers of his work could immediately understand upon reading *trek-leertje* ("they call it een trek-leertje");

I wonder what exactly was that and what was the primary use of this. How and was it used as a playing game as Antonie says he used to play with this?

**Edit:**

Upon further research, I've learnt that the text I was reading is a translation (not by Leeuwenhoek) from Dutch origin. I was able to locate a translation of this part (from Letter 83) apparently by the Royal Society, next to the original.

[Here](https://www.dbnl.org/tekst/leeu027alle10_01/leeu027alle10_01_0007.php) we can find page by page the original and English translation. (the passage starts in the penultimate paragraph of p.104 or p.105 for English):

> When I saw this, I recollected that as a boy I used to play with a piece of leather which we called a ‘pulling leather’. This was a round piece of leather with a diameter of about two inches(18). In the middle of this piece of leather we made a small hole and through this we then put a piece of string; and in front of the hole we made a knot. And when the piece of leather was soaked with water, we pressed it flat on a round Cobble, and then not only could we lift the Cobble by the string, but we also walked along with it.
> [...]

Comment: [Possible Clue](https://www.idealequestrian.com/catalogus/fournituren/trek-leertje-voor-snelsluiting/)

Comment: trek means pull in Dutch.  https://www.idealequestrian.com/catalogus/fournituren/trek-leertje-voor-snelsluiting/  googling "trek leertje nederlandse" got me [here](https://www.idealequestrian.com/catalogus/fournituren/trek-leertje-voor-snelsluiting/)  - some kinda quick mechanism?  *Helps to quickly open panic lock in an emergency, very safe!*

Comment: Initial research suggests possibly it refers to the drawstrings (originally *pulltabs*, before the advent of aluminum  cans?) on a small leather bag. I found another contemporary usage [here](https://www.vliz.be/imisdocs/publications/ocrd/251252.pdf), on page 10 4 lines below the diagram: "*Deze kussentjes schijnen min of meer de rol van trekleertjes te vervullen, en laten der vlieg toe op gladde oppervlakten (een plafond of eene vensterruit bijv.)*" -> These pads seem to play more or less the role of pull tabs, and allow the fly to move onto smooth surfaces (a ceiling or a window pane, e.g.)

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: Yes, I saw that also - but nothing with a still extant patent can possibly date back over 2 centuries. It does reinforce the "pull-tab" translation though.

Comment: From the description of the "pulling leather", it essentially is a suction cup, called [zuignap](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zuignap) in Dutch. Here the leather is made airtight, despite the small hole, by soaking it in water.

Comment: So, not a special fork for eating Prime Ministers...

Comment: @ccprog, Thanks. yep. this is probably this. I can see how we children and adults can play with this; I was just hoping to find little more sophisticated game.